# Bitbucket Pippelines EKS Container image Change

Tags: amazon-eks, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

- It is required to deploy the ECR Image to EKS via Bitbucket pipelines.

So I have created the step below. But I am not sure about the correct command for the **KUBECTL_COMMAND** to change (set) the deployment image with the new one in a namespace in the EKS cluster:

```
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment to Production'
        deployment: Production
        trigger: 'manual'
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-eks-kubectl-run:2.2.0
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              CLUSTER_NAME: 'xxx-zaferu-dev'
              KUBECTL_COMMAND: 'set image deployment.apps/xxx-dev xxx-application=123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ci-cd-test:latest'
          - echo " Deployment has been finished successfully..."
```

- So I am looking for the correct way for this step!
- If this is not the best way for the CI/CD deployment, I am planning to use basic command to change the conatiner image :

```
image: python:3.8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Update EKS deployment
        script:
          - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster-name>
          - kubectl set image deployment/<deployment-name> <container-name>=<new-image>:<tag> -n <namespace>
          - aws eks describe-cluster --name <cluster-name>
```

I tried to use:

```
KUBECTL_COMMAND: 'set image deployment.apps/xxx-dev xxx-application=123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ci-cd-test:latest'
```

but it gives an error :

```
INFO: Successfully updated the kube config.
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "xxx-app" not found
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I got my bug, a missing namespace :)

```
- kubectl set image deployment/<deployment-name> <container-name>=<new-image>:<tag> -n <namespace>
```

I forgot to add -n  and then I realized.